# Errror:Undeclared _delay_ms while programming in MPLAB X IDE

Tags: pic, mplabx

I am new to microcontroller world. Can someone help me with this? I am trying to blink my LED on dsPIC33EP512MU810  with the MPLAB X IDE and X16 compiler.

My code:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
#include xc.h
#include p33EP512MU810.h
#include libpic30.h
void main() {

TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 0;//RB0 as Output PIN

while(1) {

LATBbits.LATB0=1;  // LED ON
__delay_ms(1000); // 1 Second Delay
 LATBbits.LATB0=0;  // LED OFF
__delay_ms(1000); // 1 Second Delay
} }
```

Instead now its showing undefined reference to '_delay_ms.I have already included the header files for the device and "xc.h".

I have build the project just to check whether the code is working or not. I haven't yet done the required hardware connections in the pins. Can some one give suggestions?

---

Yes.I have already included the header file beforehand.Now,its not showing the previous error.I have corrected to this:

```
void main() 
{

TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 0;//RB0 as Output PIN

while(1)
  {

    LATBbits.LATB0=1;  // LED ON
    __delay_ms(1000); // 1 Second Delay
     LATBbits.LATB0=0;  // LED OFF
    __delay_ms(1000); // 1 Second Delay
  }
  }
```

Instead now its showing undefined reference to '_delay_ms.I have already included the header files for the device and "xc.h" .I have build the project just to check whether the code is working or not.I havent yet done the required hardware connections in the pins.Can some one give suggestions?Thanks

Comment: Could it be because you need to #include the header for your chip?

Comment: RB0 is defined as a single bit (i.e. bit 0) of a register (PORTB). In order to set it you need to specify the register as well as the bit. You should set it the same way you set TRISB0, but using PORTBbits instead. Make sure the header file for your device is included.

Comment: PLEASE do NOT delete your original question content and replace it with a new one. It renders answers to it invalid! For that I will downvote you and suggest a close to the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has deleted their original question content and replaced it with a different question, thus rendering existing answers to the question invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PORTBbits.RB0`.  `RB0` is the name of the pin, not the name of a register or a bit in a register.

There is a *different* macro available to directly get to that one bit, which is `_RB0` if you want to use shorthand.

```
#define _RB0 PORTBbits.RB0
```

(I believe this may have been a change between C24 and XC16).

Comment: I don't quite understand how this will help with undefined `_delay_ms()` function.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I am not quite sure how this answer ended up here. I didn't answer this question. This answer is for a completely different question. Something seems to have gone awry.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Ah, I see what has happened. The OP posted one question with an inability to use RB0. I answered that. The OP then deleted the entire content of their question and replaced it with a different one - thus rendering my answer invalid. Reflects badly on me, but if you look at the edits to the question you can see the OP is abusing the site's edit facilities.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't check the edit history, sorry. Upvoting, since it's a perfectly valid answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the clock frequency as follows:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000UL
```

or as:

```
#define FCY 8000000UL
```

I use the latter definition. Try with both of these.

One other thing - you need to set `RB0` as digital pin, it is configured as analog by default. Here is the complete working code:

```
#include <xc.h>

#define FCY 8000000UL
#include <libpic30.h>

int main(void) {

    ANSELBbits.ANSB0 = 0; // RB0 is digital
    LATBbits.LATB0 = 0; // RB0 is low
    TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 0; // RB0 is output

    while(1) {
        LATBbits.LATB0 = 1; // LED ON
        __delay_ms(1000);
        LATBbits.LATB0 = 0; // LED OFF
        __delay_ms(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have corrected as you have said.But the build is failed and it is still showing undeclared __delay_ms.

Comment: __delay_ms (defined in libpic30.h) requires FCY, not _XTAL_FREQ. If FCY is not defined then __delay_ms will be declared extern and must be supplied by the user.

Comment: @Inquisitive - this code compiles without any problems in my MPLAB.